# Intellij / Tomcat : NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

In my Java project, I have a class `Person` that exists in two different jars with the same package name (`com.example.beans`).

The problem is that this class is defined like this in `jar1`:

```
class Person {
   private String firstname;
   private String lastname;
   public Person(String firstname, String lastname){
       this.firstname = firstname;
       this.lastname = lastname;
   }
}
```

and in `jar2` :

```
class Person {
   private int age;
   public Person(int age){
       this.age = age;
   }
}
```

This class is used correctly in the project and IntelliJ is not complaining.
At the server (tomcat 8) startup, I got the following error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.beans.Person(Ljava/lang/String, Ljava/lang/String)
```

I suspect Tomcat loaded `Person` from `jar2` instead of `jar1`.

Question : How can I tell IntelliJ (to tell tomcat) to load the right class
depending on the signature ?

Regards.

Comment: You should not have two classes with the same name and in the same package in the same application (even though they are in different JARs). Rename one of the classes, or put it in a different package.

Comment: @Jesper Your solution is certainly the most logical but, as I'm not in charge of those two jars, I cannot.

Comment: Do you ever use the `Person` class from jar2? If IntelliJ is working ok I'm guessing not.  If so, just rename jar2 or jar1 to force jar1 on to the classpath first

Answer (score 1):

The jars should be placed in the `WEB-INF\lib` folder of the `war` files, that way, they will be loaded by different classloaders, and they won't cause such problems.

By the way, it is bad practice to name the packages in different jar files with the same name. One of the main goals of packages is correct namespacing, and this is anything but correct.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the problem : IntelliJ puts all the libs in the `my_app_exploded/WEB-INF/lib` directory where `jar1` et `jar2` co-exist.

Comment: Well, those two jars shouldn't be in the same war, as they conflict with each other. The class names should not be the same. You can't load two classes with the same fully qualified name in a single ClassLoader, that's how the JVM works.